# Selecionar apenas pasta - HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Como posso fazer um `input[type="file"]` selecionar apenas pasta, ao invés de arquivos?

Eu utilizei a marcação:
`<input type="file" multiple webkitdirectory>`
 


Mas pelo visto, ele seleciona os arquivos da pasta. Exibindo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas ao acessar a pasta, você vai estar selecionando os arquivos internos também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solução

Você pode pegar o caminho completo de um arquivo e apenas remover o nome do arquivo

## Código

O código abaixo esta comentado explicando o seu funcionamento.

```js
$('[type="file"]').on("change", function(event) {

  //Pega apenas um arquivo
  let file = event.target.files[0];
  
  //Pega o caminho do arquivo
  let caminho = file.webkitRelativePath;
  
  //Desmonta o caminho em um array
  let arrayPath = caminho.split('/');
  
  //Remove só o arquivo do caminho
  arrayPath.pop();
  
  //Controi o caminho denovo
  console.log(arrayPath.join('/'));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="ctrl" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
```

## AJuda

[How to get folder directory from HTML input type “file” or any other way?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16774922/7986223)

[HTMLInputElement.webkitdirectory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory)

## Observação importante

Se o seu projeto for uma aplicação web, apesar de conseguir pegar o caminho da pasta, você não poderá utilizar ele para manipular no futuro.

Caso precise destes arquivos, você terá que salvar no seu servidor, e então manipular, já que o seu servidor não terá mais acesso a pasta do seu usuário.

Comment: Muito bom, muito obrigado. Achei de um jeito parecido, mas o seu esta melhor.
Tem como eu exibir o diretório? 

Por exemplo: "C:/pasta-teste/pasta-um" ao invés de apenas a pasta, como "pasta-um".